# how to define constructor for Python's new NamedTuple type?

Tags: python, oop

As you may know, this is most recent type of defining named tuples in python:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class MyType(NamedTuple):
    id: int = 0
    name: str = 0
```

After defining the type, Python interpreter defines a default constructor getting id and name and you can instantiate a new object using your fields.
Now I want to initialise a new object using a string and within the function I parse it. How can I define another constructor without spoiling the good default ones?

Comment: @abarnert There's [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) now.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Ah, yeah, forgot about that…

Answer (score 20):

> How can I define another constructor without spoiling the good default ones?

You can't. Python classes can't have multiple `__new__` methods (or, if you meant "initializer", `__init__` methods), just one.

---

But there's an easy way to work around this: the *alternate constructor idiom*: you write a `@classmethod` that provides an alternate way to construct instances. There are plenty of examples in the standard library, like [`datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) and [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp). There are even a few examples in the basic builtin types, like [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).

Here's how that works:

```
class MyType(NamedTuple):
    id: int = 0
    name: str = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string_to_parse):
        id, name = … your parsing code here …
        return cls(id, name)
```

This is, of course, the same thing you'd do with a `collections.namedtuple` subclass, a `@dataclass`, or a plain-old class that had too many different ways to construct it.

---

If you really want to, the other way to do it is to provide an ugly constructor with either keyword-only parameters, or parameters that have different meanings depending on what you pass. With `NamedTuple`, you'll have to either insert an extra class in the way, or monkeypatch the class after creation, because otherwise there's no documented way of getting at the default constructor implementation.

So:

```
class _MyType(NamedTuple):
    id: int = 0
    name: str = 0

class MyType(_MyType):
    def __new__(cls, id: int=None, name: str=None, *, parseything: str=None):
        if parseything:
            if id is not None or str is not None:
                raise TypeError("don't provide both")
            id, name = … your parsing code here …
        return super().__new__(cls, id, name)
```

… or, if you prefer monkeypatching:

```
class MyType(NamedTuple):
    id: int = 0
    name: str = 0

_new = MyType.__new__
def __new__(cls, id=None, name=None, *, parseything=None):
    if parseything:
        if id is not None or str is not None:
            raise TypeError("don't provide both")
        id, name = … your parsing code here …
    return _new(cls, id, name)
MyType.__new__ = __new__
del _new
del __new__
```

… or, if you want more of a `range`-style ugly API you can do either of the above with:

```
def __new__(cls, id_or_parsey_thing: Union[int,str]=None, 
            name: str=None):
    if isinstance(id_or_parsey_thing, str):
        if name is not None:
            raise TypeError("don't provide both")
        id, name = … your parsing code here …
    else:
        id = id_or_parsey_thing
    # super().__new__ or _new here
```

Comment: You can make the `_MyType` class anonymous, if desired, like so: `class MyType(NamedTuple('_MyType', id=int, name=str)): ...`

Answer (score 4):

Yes since Python 3.6 there is a new alternative for [`namedtuple`](https://kite.com/python/docs/collections.namedtuple) - NamedTuple. Thanks to variable annotations now it is possible. So, if you previously wrote something like:

```
MyType = namedtuple('MyType', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Now you can define it as follows.
To add a new constructor just define a [`classmethod`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.classmethod):

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class MyType(NamedTuple):
    a: str
    b: int
    c: float

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s):
        a, b, c = s.split()
        return cls(a, int(b), float(c))


print(MyType.from_string('1 2 3'))
```

Comment: This is not a constructor! This is a factory method! I need a real constructor, __init__ function