# provide additional constraints when declaring typing.NamedTuple object

Tags: python-3.x, namedtuple

Using a `typing.NamedTuple object`, what is the best way to enforce additional constraints on how it can be declared?

Let's say I have a Undergraduate class where the students have have a major but I want to enforce that 'undeclared' is an unacceptable value for the major.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Undergraduate(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    major: str

    def check_major(self):
        if self.major == "undeclared":
            raise ValueError("must declare a major")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    u1 = Undergraduate("Jane", "computer science") # no errors
    u1.check_major() # no errors
    u2 = Undergraduate("John", "undeclared") # no errors
    u2.check_major() # ValueError
```

This works fine but I would like for `check_major()` to run every time I declare a new object, ie:

```py
u1 = Undergraduate("John", "undeclared") # immediate ValueError raised
```

Is this possible using only a NamedTuple (I know how to do it using traditional classes)?

**Note**: I read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943892/how-to-define-constructor-for-pythons-new-namedtuple-type). These solutions provide somewhat of a working solution, but like the OP I want to be able to instantiate the objects without requiring additional class methods to be called.

Comment: This looks like a job for an ``enum.Enum``, not ``str``. Are arbitrary majors other than ``"undeclared"`` desirable?

Comment: It's a pretty generic example, so the data are mostly irrelevant.  The actual code I'm working with (too complicated to post) is about doing various checks on the data, like type-checking, value-checking, etc.  Really all I'm interested in is running an `if` statement on the constructor every time I make a new NamedTuple of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NamedTuple` protects both `__init__` and `__new__` from being replaced at declaration. However, they can be replaced after the class was created.

```
class Radial2D(NamedTuple):
      angle: float
      length: float

      def _verify_attributes_(self, *args):
          if self.length < 0 or not 0 < self.angle < 360:
             raise ValueError('Arguments out of range')

Radial2D.__init__ = Radial2D._verify_attributes_
print(Radial2D(90, 15.5))  # Radial2D(angle=90, length=15.5)
print(Radial2D(12, -5))    # ValueError: Arguments out of range
```

This pattern can be simplified using a class decorator:

```
from typing import Type, NamedTuple


def verify(tp: Type[NamedTuple]):
    verifier = tp._verify_attributes_
    tp.__init__ = verifier
    return tp


@verify
class Undergraduate(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    major: str

    def _verify_attributes_(self, *args):
        if self.major == "undeclared":
            raise ValueError("must declare a major")


print(Undergraduate("Jane", "computer science"))  # Undergraduate(name='Jane', major='computer science')
print(Undergraduate("John", "undeclared"))        # ValueError: must declare a major
```

Comment: Great, this is the answer I was looking for.  The decorator is the ticket, thanks!